# GetBalance generate too much request

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, infura

**What I do?**.

- Download logs and collect address
- Use address to getBalance
- Result make a hodler table

**Result**

- Too much generate request to infura

**Question**
Is any function/method to make a one request?

Snippet

```go
logs, err := app.CallLogs(context.Background())
    for _, vLog := range logs {
        go func(log types.Log) {
                ....
                ether := GetUserBalance(app.instance, transferEvent.To.String()) // Generate TOO much request
                if err := hodler.InsertOrUpdate(ctx, client, transferEvent.To.String(), ether); err != nil {
                    logger.Error(err)
                }
            }
        }(vLog)
    }
```